# Number of specific one-hour periods between two date/times

Tags: sql, date

I have a table of table records, call it "game"

It has an id and timestamp.

What I need to know is unrelated to the table specifically.  In order to know the average number of games played per hour, I need to know :

- Total games played for each hour over the date range
- Number of hourly
  periods between the date range.

Finding the first is a matter of extracting the hour from the timestamp and grouping by it.
For the second, if the date range was rounded to the nearest day, finding this value would be easy (totalgames/numdays).

Unfortunately I can't assume this.  What I need help with is finding the number of **specific** hour periods existing within a time range.

Example:
If the range is 5 PM today to 8 PM tomorrow, there is one "00" hour (midnight to 1 AM), but **two** 17, 18, 19 hours (5-6, 6-7, 7-8)

Thanks for the help

Edit: for clarity, consider the following query:

I have table game:

id, daytime

```
select EXTRACT(hour from daytime) as hour_period, count (*)
from game
where daytime > dateFrom and daytime < dayTo
group by hour_period
```

This will give me the number of games played broken down into hourly chunks for the time period.

In order to find the average games played per hour, I need to know exactly how many **specific** hour durations are between two timestamps.  Simply dividing by the number of days is not accurate.

Edit:  The ideal output will look something like this:

```
00   275
01   300
02   255
...
```

Consider the following:  How many times does midnight occur between date 1 and date 2 ?  If you have 1.5 days, that doesn't guarantee that midnight will occur twice.  6 AM today to 6 PM tomorrow night, for example, has 1 midnight, but 9PM tonight to 9 AM two days from now has 2 midnights.

What I'm trying to find is how many of the EXACT HOUR occurs between two timestamps, so I can use it to average the number of games played at THAT HOUR over a time period.

Comment: It seems that you only need the number of hours elapsed between two timestamps. You can use a function like datediff, deppending on your database.

Comment: I still need to group by hour, so I need the number of midnight-1AM periods between two timestamps

Comment: See the answer below. I don't understand what you mean with "number of 1AM periods"

Comment: Which database are you using? SQL Server? Oracle?

Comment: "In order to find the average games played per hour, I need to know exactly how many specific hour durations are between two timestamps." To do this, you can count the number of hour_periods by enclosing the query above in a sub-query. I will post an answer with this approach.

Comment: To get the number of day between the `dateFrom` and the `dateTo` why don't you do `DATEDIFF(hh, dateFrom, dateTo) / 24.0` it'll give you always the exact amount of days regardless of the two time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**:

The following query gets the days, hours, and # of games, giving an output as below:

```
29 23 100
29 00 130
30 22 140
30 23 150
```

Then, the outer query adds up the number of games for each distinct hour and divides by the number of hours, as follows

```
22 140
23 125
00 130
```

The modified query is below:

```
SELECT 
hour_period,
sum(hourly_no_of_games) / count(hour_period)
FROM
(
SELECT
EXTRACT(DAY from daytime) as day_period,
EXTRACT(HOUR from daytime) as hour_period, 
count (*) hourly_no_of_games
from game
where daytime > dateFrom and daytime < dayTo
group by EXTRACT(DAY from daytime), EXTRACT(HOUR from daytime)
) hourly_data
GROUP BY hour_period
ORDER BY hour_period;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/65b8f/6)</kbd>

Comment: What you're missing is the **per hour** count.  I need to know, for each individual hour, how many games were played.
I don't need the number of games played at each hour, and I don't need the number of games played per hour total.

Comment: So, the hours could repeat across days (for e.g. if the date range is 05/20/2014 10 am - 05/23/2014 5 pm, then there would be 4 11 hours and 2 18 hours). The number of games must be added up for each hour (11, 18, etc.) and divided by the number of occurrences of the hours (3, 2, etc.). I hope that I have understood what you need correctly. I have changed the query above accordingly.

Comment: Made a couple more syntax corrections and tested the query on SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Yes I think you have the right idea.  Get day and hour, and then group them at the highest level.  Thanks for the update

Answer (score 0):

If you need something to GROUP BY, you can truncate the timestamp to the level of hour, as in the following:

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME
SET @Date = GETDATE()

SELECT @Date, DATEADD(Hour, DATEDIFF(Hour, 0, @Date), 0) AS RoundedDate
```

If you just need to find the total hours, you can just select the DATEDIFF in hours, such as with

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(Hour, '5/29/2014 20:01:32.999', GETDATE())
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think I'm not being clear in my question.  Please see the edit

Answer (score 0):

Extract not only the hour of the day but the day of the year (1-366). Then group on those. If there is the possibility the interval could span a year, then add the year itself and group by all three.

```
year  dy hr games
2013 365 23 115
2014   1 00 103
```